# How to erase rows in a data frame R

Tags: r

I have a data frame that look like this:

```
Quality     Data     Name  
  1          667     green  
  3          647     white   
  1          626     Blue  
  2          345     yellow  
  1          550     Blue 
  5          730     green
```

i want a code that goes through a for loop and takes the one less the 600 and greater than 700 and delete the row && all the ones with the same name and saves the ones that were deleted in another data frame
example

```
 for i in nrow(df){  
       if (df$Data[i]<=600 || df$Data[i]>=700){ 
          Subset_by_name=subset(df,df$Name==df$Name[i]) (saves bad samples)
          (delete from data)
          Subset_by_name=data.frame(Subset_by_name) 
          bad_sample=rbind(Subset_by_name)  (saves all the bad data in a data frame)
    }  
    }
```

result
bad_sample

```
Quality     Data    Name  
  1          667     green   
  1          626     Blue  
  2          345     yellow  
  1          550     Blue    
  5          730     green
```

data

```
Quality     Data    Name     
  3          647     white
```

help please????

Comment: your question says <600 but your code is checking for <600 and >700. What do you actually want?

Comment: srry i edited it now

Comment: `bad <- df[df$Name %in% df[df$Data < 600 | df$Data > 700, 'Name'],] ; good <- df[!df$Name %in% df[df$Data < 600 | df$Data > 700, 'Name'],]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you really need is subsetting; see [the R tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info) for lots of tutorials about how it works.

```
bad <- df[df$Name %in% df[df$Data < 600 | df$Data > 700, 'Name'],]
good <- df[!df$Name %in% df[df$Data < 600 | df$Data > 700, 'Name'],]

bad
##   Quality Data   Name
## 1       1  667  green
## 3       1  626   Blue
## 4       2  345 yellow
## 5       1  550   Blue
## 6       5  730  green

good
##   Quality Data  Name
## 2       3  647 white
```

Answer (score 2):

We can do this easily with `split`.  The output will be `list` and if we need it in two `data.frame` objects, it can be done but it is better to have it in a `list`

```
lst <- split(df1, with(df1, Name %in% Name[Data < 600 |Data > 700]))
good_sample <- lst[[1]]
good_sample
#   Quality Data  Name
#2       3  647 white

bad_sample <- lst[[2]]
bad_sample 
#  Quality Data   Name
#1       1  667  green
#3       1  626   Blue
#4       2  345 yellow
#5       1  550   Blue
#6       5  730  green
```

Or instead of doing the same operation twice,

```
i1 <- with(df1, Name %in% Name[Data < 600 |Data > 700])
good_sample <- df1[i1,]
bad_sample <- df[!i1,]
```

NOTE: We are just using the operation once to `split` it.

Answer (score 2):

The `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
bad <- df %>% filter(Data < 600 | Data > 700)
good <- df %>% filter(!(Data < 600 | Data > 700))
```

Or to do this in one step and add a new column and keep all the data together

```
df <- df %>% mutate(quality = ifelse((Data < 600 | Data > 700) , "bad", "good"))
```

For operations where you need good data only

```
df %>% filter(quality == "good") %>% select(-quality)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `data.table` solution:

It's much better to add an *identifier* column to the original table instead of splitting it into two tables.

```
require(data.table)
dt[, result := "good"][Name %in% Name[Data %between% c(600, 700)], result := "bad"]
dt
#    Quality Data   Name result
# 1:       1  667  green    bad
# 2:       3  647  white    bad
# 3:       1  626   Blue    bad
# 4:       2  345 yellow   good
# 5:       1  550   Blue    bad
# 6:       5  730  green    bad
```

This updates your original `data.table` by reference.

where,

```
dt = fread('Quality     Data     Name  
           1          667     green  
           3          647     white   
           1          626     Blue  
           2          345     yellow  
           1          550     Blue 
           5          730     green')
```